# Next Js: URL is changing but page is empty

Tags: next.js, next-router

I am new in Next Js. Whenever I click on the link it updates the URL but the page is not showing any data. But in Elements data is present.

here is the code of nav file:

```html
<li className="nav-item active">
                  <Link href="/">
                    <a className="nav-link">
                      Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="/about">
                    <a className="nav-link">About</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="/blog">
                    <a className="nav-link">Blog</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="/services">
                    <a className="nav-link">Services</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
```

Blog.js file:

```html
import React from "react";

const Blog = () => {
  return <h1>Blog</h1>;
};

export default Blog;
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: I update the question. Data is present in  "Elements" chrome dev tools but not showing on page

Comment: To clarify, when you click on the "Blog" link in your nav the browser navigates to the `/blog` page but you can't see the `Blog` heading? Can you share you `pages` folder structure?

Comment: Yes, exactly. how can I share a pic here?                                                                           And one thing more HomePage is working fine only other pages like blog, services, etc nothing showing.

Comment: I update the question again.

Comment: Do you maybe have some CSS applied that could be hiding some elements? I can't see anything wrong in terms of Next.js setup.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, CSS causing the problem.